# best way of counting number of items based on condition python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Hi guys I have multiple conditions to check on a array of objects for example :

My sample array is like this

```
[{"id":1 , "type":"viw"},{"id":1 , "type":"edit"},{"id":1 , "type":"crt"}]
```

as these records will be in 10000's I want to calculate total sum of these in best way possible .

Currently doing like this

```
   view_count = [element for element in user_record if element['type'] == "viw"  ]
   edit_count = [element for element in user_record if element['type'] == "edit"]
   crt_count = [element for element in user_record if element['type'] =="crt"]

   and then len(crt_count) ,len(edit_count) ,len(view_count)
```

which seems to me a little expensive . kindly guide can I do it in optimize way ?

and 2nd question can I use OR condition with if in this list comprehension ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just collect each of the 'types' into a dictionary key and count them with it's value

```
result = {}
for element in user_record:
   try:
        result[element["type"]] += 1
   except KeyError: 
        result[element["type"]] = 1
```

per comment from @Not A Robot :
"another way for essentially the same idea:"

```
collections.Counter(map(operator.itemgetter('type'), my_list))
```

Second Question: Answer is yes you can use `or` like this:

```
edit_count = [element for element in user_record if element['type'] == "edit" or element['type'] == 'viw']
```

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
d={}
for dct in sample_arr:
    key = dct['type']
    if d.get(key) is None:
        d[key] = 0
    d[key] += 1

dict(d)
 {'viw': 1, 'edit': 1, 'crt': 1}
```

or use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict  
e = defaultdict(int)
for dct in sample_arr:
    e[dct['type']] +=1
dict(e)
 {'viw': 1, 'edit': 1, 'crt': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned with avoiding multiple iterations, just count through one iteration:

```
sample_arr = [{"id":1 , "type":"viw"},{"id":1 , "type":"edit"},{"id":1 , "type":"crt"}]

view_count, edit_count, crt_count = 0, 0, 0

for d in sample_arr:
    if d['type'] == 'viw':
        view_count += 1
    elif d['type'] == 'edit':
        edit_count += 1
    elif d['type'] == 'crt':
        crt_count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

another option without using `for` loop (but using extra memory):

```
import pandas as pd

arr = [{"id":1 , "type":"viw"},{"id":1 , "type":"edit"},{"id":1 , "type":"crt"},
       {"id":2 , "type":"viw"},{"id":2 , "type":"edit"},{"id":2 , "type":"crt"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
res = df['type'].value_counts().to_dict()

>>> res
{'viw': 2, 'edit': 2, 'crt': 2}
```

Comment: It also requires importing a fairly large library into memory plus the overhead of constructing a new data type, plus the overhead of converting it back to a python dict.